# Tailwind CSS multi level dropdown on hover

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the below tailwind CSS code which is a single level drop down on hover. Looking for help on one more level of drop down i.e, by hovering on 1, should display 1.1,1.2,1.3 to right of 1 (in a flex-col). similarly for 2 and 3. Appreciate your help.

```
    <div class="p-20">
      <div class="group inline-block relative">
        <button
          class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
        >
          <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
          <svg
            class="fill-current h-4 w-4"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
          >
            <path
              d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"
            />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <ul class="absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1 group-hover:block">
          <li class="">
            <a
              class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap"
              href="#"
              >1</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a
              class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap"
              href="#"
              >2</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a
              class="rounded-b bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap"
              href="#"
              >3</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested groups in tailwind v3.

read more about this -> [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#differentiating-nested-groups).

like this:

```
<div class="p-20">
  <div class="group/main inline-block relative">
    <button class="bg-gray-300 text-gray-700 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">
      <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
      <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <ul class="absolute hidden text-gray-700 pt-1 group-hover/main:block">
      <li class="group/item">
        <a class="rounded-t bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">1</a>
        <ul class="absolute hidden l-10 text-gray-700 pt-1 group-hover/item:block top-0 left-14">
          <li>1.1</li>
          <li>1.2</li>
          <li>1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a class="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a class="rounded-b bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-400 py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap" href="#">3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Can you help with - First level dropdown (1,2,3) width should be same as parent (dropdown). Also 1.1,1.2 and 1.3 should be clickable that leads to a different page.

Comment: @kishorenaidu your comment is not related to initial question. This answer should be accepted as it covers nested groups on hover. If you wish to have full width dropdown and links within add `inset-x-0` class to `ul` (or try another solution) on your own (test code within [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/))

Comment: @kishorenaidu you can use css for that like in main dropdown, eg use <a> tag same/similar as on parents, like <li class=""><a class="....">1.1</a></li> you can play with css to like as you want

Answer (score 0):

Nested group hovers doesn't work in Tailwind. So you need to use either [Tailwind labeled groups plugin](https://github.com/onmax/tailwindcss-labeled-groups) or another solution in tailwind community.

By plugin it would be something like that : https://play.tailwindcss.com/zJnMxyGu6X

Comment: Since [v3.2 release](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-2#nested-group-and-multiple-peer-support-using-variant-modifiers) Tailwind supports nested groups